# How to detect non-unique index on a datatable imported from Access?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access

I have an Access database with some tables that have non-unique indexes for optimized performance.
I'm trying to port the Access database to MySQL via vb.net. Once I have the schema imported into a dataset, I can easily detect primary keys and unique fields, but I'm having trouble detecting non-unique indexes that aren't primary keys.

Is there a way to either check a datacolumn object for a non-unique index flag, or check the datatable object's constraints for non-unique indexed columns?

Comment: You might look at the `OleDbConnection.GetSchema` method.  I'm not sure whether it will give you information about indexes or not but it's the first place I'd look.

Comment: what does this question have to do with jquery datatables?

Comment: sorry, mis-tagged. has to do with .net datatable object, I didn't pay close attention to the "datatable" flag. removed the flag.

Comment: For now, having to use DAO library to get tableDefs and get a list of indexes for each tableDef. All the rest of my code is using oleDB, so this is a major pain. If anyone has suggestions, they will be appreciated since this workaround is almost taking more time than it's worth.